# Access static const in another class.

Tags: c++, c++11, static, constants

A static const variable declared and defined in a class. How to access it in the private access of another class in same project. Is it possible?

```
//in some header file
Class A{
    public:
    //some data

    private:
        static const uint8_t AVar =1;
        //other data
};


//in some another header file
Class B{
    static const Bvar; 
};
//here inside Class B it possible to give Bvar  = AVar ? If yes, How ?
```

Comment: please neglect the numbers 1), 2), 3) and so on.

Comment: `friend` is your friend :) But I'd avoid this, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

A clean way to avoid duplication of the magic value without weakening encapsulation of either class is to move the magic value to a different place that is publicly accessible to both classes.

For example:

```
namespace detail {
    enum MAGIC_NUMBER_T {
        MAGIC_NUMBER = 1
    };
}

class A{
  private:
  static const uint8_t AVar = detail::MAGIC_NUMBER;
};

class B{
     static const uint8_t BVar = detail::MAGIC_NUMBER;
};
```

Comment: this is probably the best way, but i have to take MISRA rules into consideration and while we use Namespace, we have to use 'Using' directive (Using Namespace NameoftheNamespace) which again is not allowed by MISRA... But fundamentally it looks impossible to give one Private static const Variable into another one of different class....