# A static const variable declared and defined in a class. How to access it in the private access of another class in same project. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, static, constants

```
//in some header file

Class A{
public:
    //some data

private:
    static const uint8_t AVar =1;
    //other data
};

//in some another header file
Class B{
    static const Bvar;
}; 

//here inside Class B it possible to give Bvar = AVar ? If yes, How ?
```

i have to write a code considering MISRA
(issue is replacing all CONSTANT MACROs with static const 
but then how to access these static const in another file and these other data members are with static const again)

here the Namespace creation and providing variables from it to any class member looks clean way. this is probably the best way, but i have to take MISRA rules into consideration and while we use Namespace, we have to use 'Using' directive (Using Namespace NameoftheNamespace) which again is not allowed by MISRA... But fundamentally it looks impossible to give one Private static const Variable into another one of different class (without use of Namespace).... Opinions ????

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access static const in another class.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994516/access-static-const-in-another-class)

Comment: The whole point of making it private is to deny access to it. If you don't want to do that, then don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to access a private static constant variable, you want to `Replace a constant macro with static const`.

The macro was public before, why should the variable be private now?

Anyway, if you still want to go for the private approach there is another option (at the cost of high coupling): make them friends!

```
//A.h
class A {
    static int _A;
    friend class B; // there's no need to include B.h
};

//A.cpp
int A::_A = 10;

// B.h
class B {
        static int _B;
};

//B.cpp
#include "A.h"
int B::_B = A::_A;
```

There's another option, which will stand between those two:

```
// constants.h
namespace myMacros {
    extern static const int _A;
}

// constants.cpp
const int myMacros::_A = 10;
```

Comment: Note: Misra probably prohibits to use 'friend'

Comment: the Namespace creation and providing variables from it to any class member looks clean way. this is probably the best way, but i have to take MISRA rules into consideration and while we use Namespace, we have to use 'Using' directive (Using Namespace NameoftheNamespace) which again is not allowed by MISRA... But fundamentally it looks impossible to give one Private static const Variable into another one of different class (without use of Namespace).... Opinions ????

Comment: @dousin I have been trying to find any rule about 'friend' usage, but can't find anything. Was expecting the same as you just wrote, but nothing! 
But it kinda makes sense, since you can make private things accessible by some safety critical classes at the cost of bypassing class encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the private variable using a public 'getter' function. If you need access to a static variable, you must use a static method.

```
class A { 
    public: 
    inline static uint8_t GetA() { return AVar; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the variable `AVar` is in the private section of the class A, class B has no way to access it. If you need class B to access AVar, you need to change the code. The best is to move it to the public section of class A.